# Sintaxe IF dentro de um ECHO

Tags: php, if

Estou com um problema de sintaxe ao tentar colocar um `if` dentro de um `echo` em PHP.

Verifiquem o código:

```
foreach($resultadoBusca as $escrever){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $escrever['cod_votoran'] . "</td>
    <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['empresa_user']) . "</td>
    <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['cidade_user']) . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['estado_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['fone_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['cpfcnpj_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['email_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['status_user'] . "</td>
    <td>".if($escrever['status_user']=='ativo'){."<a href=\"ativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-check\" title=\"Ativar Usuário!\"></i></a>"}."<a href=\"editarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-edit\" title=\"Editar Usuário!\"></i></a><a href=\"excluirUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-remove\" title=\"Remover Usuário!\"></i></a></td></tr>";
}
```

Sei que os erros estão ocorrendo bem na parte onde começa o `if`. Pois se eu tirar ele fora funciona normalmente. Erro que ocorre assim.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Não podes por um `if` dentro de um `echo`. A função `echo` serve para imprimir *strings*, e não podes colocar código (instruções) dentro de uma *string* senão não vai funcionar.

Convém terminar o `echo` sempre que quiseres por mais código:

```
foreach($resultadoBusca as $escrever){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $escrever['cod_votoran'] . "</td>
    <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['empresa_user']) . "</td>
    <td>" . utf8_encode($escrever['cidade_user']) . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['estado_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['fone_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['cpfcnpj_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['email_user'] . "</td>
    <td>" . $escrever['status_user'] . "</td>
    <td>";
    if($escrever['status_user']=='ativo')
    {
        echo "<a href=\"ativarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-check\" title=\"Ativar Usuário!\"></i></a>"
    }
    echo "<a href=\"editarUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-edit\" title=\"Editar Usuário!\"></i></a>";
    echo "<a href=\"excluirUsuario.php?cod=".$escrever['cod_user']."\"><i class=\"icon-remove\" title=\"Remover Usuário!\"></i></a></td>
                        </tr>";
}
```

Comment: Esta resposta serviu direitinho :D Obrigado Jorge.

Answer (score 13):

Para usar *if* dentro de um echo, precisa fazer uso de um *operador ternario* todo entre parenteses: `( (condição) ? true : false )`

---

```
$id = 1;
echo 'Olá ' . ( ($id === 1) ? 'id-1' : 'id-2' );
```

**output**: `Ola id-1`

Mais sobre [**operador ternario**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: Tem algum motivo o down vote?

Comment: Também não entendi o down. Resposta simples e direta.

Comment: Sem dúvida, essa resposta foi mais direta a pergunta.

Comment: parabéns @PapaCharlie ótima resposta